# Move python modules to subdirectory without breaking imports

Tags: python

Original project `foo`:

```
/foo
    /module_a
        /module_aa
    /module_b
    ...
```

Where in the original project, `module_b` contains imports such as `import module_a`

In the new project, `bar` I'd like to have:

```
/bar
    app.py
    /foo
        /module_a
            /module_aa
        /module_b
    ...
```

However, this breaks the imports in the `foo` subdirectory:

```
    File "/bar/foo/module_b"
        import module_a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_a'
```

What should I do here, to avoid having to update/modify all of the import statements in the `foo` directory?

Answer (score 1):

This is what [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) are for. Change

```
import module_a
```

to

```
import .module_a
```

so that `module_b` will look in its own package for `module_a`, rather than in a directory on the Python search path that no longer contains `module_a`.

Comment: I would prefer to not modify any of the original modules from `foo`

Comment: The alternative is to add `/bar/foo` directly to Python's search path, but I would not necessarily recommend that.

Comment: How you execute the code matters: when you run a script, the directory containing the script is implicitly added to the front of the search path.  In your original project, it sounds like your script was in `foo`, rather than a directory that contained `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest I was able to get it working without modifying any of the original codebase:

`/foo/__init__.py`

```
import sys

sys.path.append("../foo")

from module_a import some_function_a
from module_b import some_other_function_b

sys.path.remove("../foo")
```

`app.py`

```
import foo

foo.somefunction_a()
foo.some_other_function_b()
```